# How to conditionally copy files using ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Please refer to the config below, the idea being, do a deploy of the config if the config file is found

I tried many variations of expressing this idea, especially in the last 3 lines, but I am unable to wrap my head around **joining the results of the stat loop with my deploy loop** in a meaningful way

I have my list of structs like:

```
config_vars:
  - war_name: TestNode_app1.war
    standalone_name: jboss_standalone.xml
    jboss_service_name: jboss_app1
    jboss_folder: jboss_app1
  - war_name: TestNode_app2.war
    standalone_name: jboss_app2_standalone.xml
    jboss_service_name: jboss_app2
    jboss_folder: jboss_app2
```

In the playbook I have

```
...
...

tasks:
  - name: check if war exists
    stat:
      path: files/wars/{{ item.war_name }}
    register: war_file
    loop: "{{ config_vars }}"

  - name: Deploy config file
    copy: src=files/wars/{{ item.war_name }} dest=/opt/{{ item.jboss_folder }}/standalone/deployments/{{ item.war_name }}
    when: item.stat.exists
    loop: "{{ config_vars }}"
    with_items: war_file.results
```

Expected results: For a war file that exists, the deploy loop should pick it up and do the copy. and if not exist, no action
Actual result: various. For the above config, I have:

```
ERROR! duplicate loop in task: items
The offending line appears to be:


    - name: deploy WAR file
      ^ here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you do have `duplicate loop in task`: `loop` and `with_items` are both loop constructs.

Here is a simple playbook to demonstrate how to achieve this. You don't even need to use the `with_together` construct that Matt P provided, however you may want to for readability.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    config_vars:
      - filepath: ./f1.txt
        other: 'here'
      - filepath: ./f2.txt
        other: 'also here'
  tasks:
    - name: check if war exists
      stat:
        path: "{{ item.filepath }}"
      register: war_file
      loop: "{{ config_vars }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Copying {{ item.item }}"
      when: item.stat.exists
      loop: "{{ war_file.results }}"
```

And the result (given only f2.txt exists):

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [check if war exists] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'filepath': './f1.txt', 'other': 'here'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'filepath': './f2.txt', 'other': 'also here'})

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'stat': {'exists': False}, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'path': './f1.txt', 'follow': False, 'get_checksum': True, 'get_mime': True, 'get_attributes': True, 'checksum_algorithm': 'sha1', 'get_md5': None}}, 'failed': False, 'item': {'filepath': './f1.txt', 'other': 'here'}, 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'stat': {'exists': True, 'path': './f2.txt', 'mode': '0644', 'isdir': False, 'ischr': False, 'isblk': False, 'isreg': True, 'isfifo': False, 'islnk': False, 'issock': False, 'uid': 501, 'gid': 20, 'size': 0, 'inode': 8626896681, 'dev': 16777220, 'nlink': 1, 'atime': 1572930945.6961422, 'mtime': 1572930850.452235, 'ctime': 1572930850.452235, 'wusr': True, 'rusr': True, 'xusr': False, 'wgrp': False, 'rgrp': True, 'xgrp': False, 'woth': False, 'roth': True, 'xoth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isgid': False, 'blocks': 0, 'block_size': 4096, 'device_type': 0, 'flags': 0, 'generation': 0, 'birthtime': 1572930850.452235, 'readable': True, 'writeable': True, 'executable': False, 'pw_name': 'pwd', 'gr_name': 'staff', 'checksum': 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709', 'mimetype': 'unknown', 'charset': 'unknown', 'version': None, 'attributes': [], 'attr_flags': ''}, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'path': './f2.txt', 'follow': False, 'get_checksum': True, 'get_mime': True, 'get_attributes': True, 'checksum_algorithm': 'sha1', 'get_md5': None}}, 'failed': False, 'item': {'filepath': './f2.txt', 'other': 'also here'}, 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) => {
    "msg": "Copying {'filepath': './f2.txt', 'other': 'also here'}"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Notice that the `item` dictionary element is provided in each element of `war_file.results`. This `item` contains the item used in the `stat` loop.

Here is more information on loops: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Comment: Didn't notice that ... nice find

Comment: Thank @MattP, indeed, a nice feature.

Answer (score 3):

This is achievable with `loop` and `zip` (replacement for the old `with_together` loop).

```
  - name: Deploy config file
    copy: src=files/wars/{{ item.0.war_name }} dest=/opt/{{ item.0.jboss_folder }}/standalone/deployments/{{ item.0.war_name }}
    when: item.1.stat.exists
    loop: "{{ config_vars | zip(war_file.results) | list }}"
```

This will produce fairly verbose output, so if you'd like to minimize it add something like:

```
  loop_control:
    label: "Copy {{ item.0.war_name }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both of you. The below is now working well:

```
tasks:
  - name: check if war exists
    local_action: stat path=files/wars/{{ item.war_name }}
    register: war_file
    loop: "{{ config_vars }}"

  - name: deploy war file
    become: yes
    become_user: jboss-as
    copy: |
      src=files/wars/{{ item.item.war_name }}
      dest=/opt/{{ item.item.jboss_folder }}/standalone/deployments/{{ item.item.war_name }}
    when: item.stat.exists
    loop: "{{ war_file.results }}"
```